# How to make zsh completion show all args?

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh

my system: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

zsh version: zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

git version: 2.26.2

---

zsh completion code

```
#compdef logs
args="`git branch -a | grep ${!#} | sed 's/\*//g' | sed 's/remotes\///g'`"
args="$args `git tag -l | grep "${!#}"`"
_arguments "*: :($args)"
```

when i use `logs` in a git path

```
> logs <tab>
zsh: do you wish to see all 150 possibilities (50 lines)?
```

when i use `git branch -a | wc -l` and `git tag -l | wc -l` in the same path

```
> git branch -a | wc -l
109
> git tag -l | wc -l
288
```

---

I have branch names like `release/v3.5.4-abc` and `release/v3.5.3-xxx`.

The command line will show nothing when I use `logs 3.5.4<tab>`.

But it will give me `release/v3.5.3-xxx` when I use `logs 3.5.3<tab>`.

It seems that some candidates have been thrown away.

How can I get all candidates?

Comment: You might want to use the `--format` option rather than trying to post-process the default output of `git branch`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the reply. Actually, I have an alias like `logs = log --format='%Cyellow%h %Cauto%d %Creset%s%n  %Cdim%cn  %ar  %cd%Creset' --graph`. What I need is a `git log` that supports fuzzy search for branch names and tags. Example: when I type `git logs 5.4<tab>` , zsh completion can match like `release/v3.5.4-abc`. My zsh completion code can meet this requirement, but it seems that some candidates have been thrown away.

Comment: No, I mean use `git branch --format` to produce output that doesn't contain a `*` that you need to strip out. There are also plumbing commands that are probably more suitable than `branch`.

Comment: ( ´▽｀) Ok, I got it. I fixed my code -> `args="\`git branch -r --format='%(refname:short)' -l "*"${words[CURRENT]}"*"\`"`. At the same time, I also found that I should use `${words[CURRENT]}` instead of `${!#}` to get the last element. Thanks again! ^_^